Should I put my MCAT score on a CV for a sessional position?
I'm applying for a sessional lecturer position for an ethics course in a biology department heavy on pre-meds. I don't have a PhD but am an ideal candidate in every other respect. Will including my MCAT (medical school admissions) score demonstrate anything of value considering my biology background is light?

In your shoes, I would. The thing with Resumes and CVs is that what you include or don't changes as your career progresses. Putting MCAT scores would look silly when applying for a TT Assistant Professor position, but would be central for a grad student applying for a job in say, MCAT test prep. Since your Biology background is light and you say the department has a lot of pre-meds, a high MCAT is the sort of thing that might impress your premed students and thus the kind of thing those hiring might appreciate.
